# Linux: Copy Files created on sunday

Tags: linux, centos

I have a script, and want to copy only files, which are created on a sunday.

`find /data/src/ -iname *.bak -mmin +3 -type f -exec cp {} -n -p -v /data/dest \;`

Alternative files which created on 7. , 14. , 21. 28. th of the month.

Maybe we can use the filename for this options?

Filenames like:

```sh
db1_backup_2021_10_27_233001_1582165.bak
db1_backup_2021_10_28_233001_1582165.bak
db2_backup_2021_10_28_233001_1582165.bak
...
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

### you can use the find command :

```
 cp  `find . -type f -newermt '18 sep 2016 20:05:00'` FOLDER
```

Or :

```
 cp `find -type f -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' | egrep "^(Sun)" | cut -f 2-`
```

Keep in mind this is not the creation date but the last modificationd date

### as script with the name of the file:

```
## declare an array variable put here the dates
eclare -a arr=("07" "14" "21" "28")

## now loop through the above array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "copying back from " + $i
   cp "db"*"_backup_"*"_"*"$i"*".bak" ./sundaysBackups/
   # or do whatever with individual element of the array
done

echo "ls in sundays"
ls ./sundaysBackups
```

you can try this with the name of the file :

```
cp "db"*"_backup_"*"_"*"_07_"*".bak" 
cp "db"*"_backup_"*"_"*"_14_"*".bak"
cp "db"*"_backup_"*"_"*"_21_"*".bak"
cp "db"*"_backup_"*"_"*"_28_"*".bak"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution!   

*cp -n -p -v `find /data/src/ -iname *.bak -mtime +15 -type f -printf '%Ta\t%p\n' | egrep "^(Sun)" | cut -f 2-` /data/dst/;*

Comment: @sql_usr001 try the script version ! It actually uses the name of the file instead of the last modification :)